OpenSearch minimum should match nto working properly
If I run this query below:
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 4,
  "query": {
    "match":{
      "court_name": 
      {
        "query": "Texas",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "minimum_should_match": "2<10% 3<30% 4<20%"
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm able to find the document. But when I add an irrelevant word like "Texas banana" it finds no results! It should still find the document that was found earlier. What's happening?

can you provide the type the field court_name

"court_name": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "standard",
"search_analyzer": "whitespace",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword"
}
}
},

the parameter minimum_should_match in the match clause define the number of words that the match query should match in your example you specify 2<10% which means if the match query contains 2 words or less it must match the two words in order to return a results if the query contains more than 2 words it should match 10% of the given words in your case if you try "Texas banana apple" instead of "Texas banana" you will match the document that you re looking for

oh ok so: if it's one word or two words it should match 100% . And anything above it, will accept round _down(N words * percentage%)
